# How to do Countdown algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am new to programming, and on our programming class, we were asked to do an algorithm that counts the day before Christmas given a date. I have already an algorithm in mind, but it needs defining the number of days there are before Christmas for each month, then a lot of if-else statements. I was just wondering if there is another more efficient algorithm to this problem. I am writing this in pseudocode.

This is what I have done so far:

```
define jan=359, feb=328, mar=306, apr=269, may=239, jun=208, jul=178, aug=147, sep=116, oct=86, nov=55, dec=25

input mm
input dd

if mm is jan
     days= jan - dd
...
```

Comment: Please publish the attempted solution you have come up with so far - this is not a homework service.

Comment: I'm assuming this is in pseudo-code, if not please state what language you're doing it in. You should use a while loop ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop ). Have the loop run while it is not Christmas, and for every time it loops, increment a counter variable.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Also note that this problem is quite a standard one, and several solutions exist on the internet. I don't think posting the question here was necessary

Comment: When you're definining those month-days before Christmas, you could as well define all 365 (or 366?) days... but that's not "programming"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a countdown function,

```
let dayMilli = (24*60*60*1000);
let hourMilli = (60*60*1000);
let minuteMilli = (60*1000);
let secondMilli = (1000);

function printTime(millis){
  var days = millis/dayMilli;
  var lessDay = millis % dayMilli;

  var hours = lessDay/hourMilli;
  var lessHour = lessDay % hourMilli;

  var minute = lessHour/minuteMilli;
  var lessMinute = lessHour % minuteMilli;

  var second = lessMinute / secondMilli;
  $("#myTime").text(parseInt(days) + " Days " + parseInt(hours) + " Hours " + parseInt(minute) + " Minutes " + parseInt(second) + " Seconds");

}
```

and if you need a countdown for every second you can try

```
//call every seconds the function update
var myVar = setInterval(update, 1000);

//date of christmas
var christmas = new Date(2018, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0)

//update time difference
function update(){
  printTime(getTimeDif(christmas));
}

//get milliseconds difference from today to christmas 
function getTimeDif(dateBefore){
  return (dateBefore.getTime()- new Date()).getTime());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to wrap my mind around it and try to apply the concept in my algorithm.

Comment: I would have to do it in algorithm where there is no date variable type. But thanks!